# iframe element hide my page below

Tags: html, iframe

I have a simple html page with iframe and text.
Why I cant see the text: "Test" inside `<p>` element?
What I'm doing wrong at my .html file?
When I removed the `<iframe>` elemnt i can see "Test"

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p align="right">
   <iframe id="serviceFrame" src="http://www.cnn.com" width="100"    height="52"  frameborder="0"/>
 </p>

<p align="left">
Test
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Basic automated QA](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use self-closing (`<iframe ... />`) tags with an `iframe`.

The `/` at the and is ignored and the `<iframe>`  tag is still open, so your `<p>` tag is *within* your `iframe`.

You need to correctly close your `iframe` and use `</iframe>`

Comment: Oh..Thanks..solved my problem:)